# How to automate rsync without asking for password prompt

Tags: ssh, rsync

I would like to automate the rsync task as a cron job. Since it needs the passphrase I am not able to do the cronjob. I need to specify the passphrase along with the rsync command or I will store the passphrase in a file and I will read from it. My command will look like this:

```
rsync -aPe "ssh -i ' . $server->{'ssh_key'} . '" ' . $server_lock_dir;
```

So where do I put the password ?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to do that - just need to set up a pair of ssh keys and put the public key in the remote system's .ssh directory.

Then you just do this:

```
rsync -a -e ssh /local/path/ server:/remote/path/
```

(Note that `-e ssh` has been the default for quite a few years now, so you can probably omit it, unless you're using a very old version.)

There's a "how to" guide on setting up the keys [here](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html).

Comment: The OP mentions the use of a sshkey with a passphrase. How does this solve the passphrase input?

Comment: Most guides recommend creating the keys without a passphrase.

Comment: Watch out: if you run your command with `sudo` it will prompt for a password even with an SSH key pair.

Answer (score 6):

If you want this to work from cron, you have several possibilities:

- setup password-less ssh keys - not very secure
- setup password-less ssh keys, but combine them with ssh ForceCommand in the authorized_keys file to limit the commands that can be run with that ssh key. See man sshd, google on "ssh ForceCommand"
- setup passworded ssh keys, but combine them with keychain to keep the key in memory between sessions. I've written a blog post on this: [ssh, ssh-agent, keychain and cron notes](http://soniahamilton.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/ssh-ssh-agent-keychain-and-cron-notes/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to copy files remotely:

1. Make sure you have a public key on your local machine that can log into the remote machine.(in this case the my ssh-key is "/home/myaccount/.ssh/id_rsa"
2. Specify local folder you want to sync with the remote, in my case "/home/myaccount/mysourcefolder"
3. Specify the destination folder full path in the remote server, in my case remoteaccount@remoteserver:"/home/remoteaccount/mydestinationfolder/"

---

Note:

- --progress is to show progress for each file being copied
- -a to transfer recusively all files in the mysourcefolder
- -v for verbosity
- -z to compress data portions for small files

My command will look like below:

> rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh -i /home/myaccount/.ssh/id_rsa"
>   /home/myaccount/mysourcefolder
>   remoteaccount@remoteserver:"/home/remoteaccount/mydestinationfolder/"

Comment: How exactly did you create "/home/myaccount/.ssh/id_rsa" and what is written in there? Is it the password for the remote server in plaintext (without encryption)?
I don't want other users of my computer (including the admin) to be able to read my password.