# Unable to pass server password with Popen in Django?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am unable to pass server password with subprocess.Popen in Django. Here's my full views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
import subprocess

def upload_file(request):
    '''This function produces the form which allows user to input session_name, their remote host name, username 
    and password of the server. User can either save, load or cancel the form. Load will execute couple Linux commands
    that will list the files in their remote host and server.'''

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        # session_name = request.POST['session']
        url = request.POST['hostname']
        username = request.POST['username']
        global password
        password = request.POST['password']
        global source
        source = str(username) + "@" + str(url)

        command = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': password}).communicate()[0]

        result1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/home/zurelsoft/R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        result = ''.join(result1)
        return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'res':result, 'res1':command}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        pass
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': 'form'},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here's the form that I take user input from:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Session</legend>
                <label for="input-one" class="float"><strong>Session Name:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="session" id="sess" type="text" size="30" /><br />

                <label for="input-two" class="float"><strong>RemoteHost:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="hostname"  id="host" type="text" size="30" />

                <label for="input-three" class="float"><strong>Username:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="username"  id="user" type="text" size="30" />

                <label for="input-four" class="float"><strong>Password:</strong></label><br />
                <input class="inp-text" name="password"  id="pass" type="password" size="30" />
        </fieldset>
```

What am I doing wrong? Password is not passed from environment_variable.

Comment: Can you show more of your view code? You're missing some essential lines there

Comment: Done. Please check out the question.

Comment: The `global password` part is a _really_ bad idea imho. Using globals is generally a bad idea but for a password seems possibly quite dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Your code (as far as setting the password in `RSYNC_PASSWORD`) is correct.

My conclusion is that you are trying to connect to a server with a different module in Rsync like ssh. In the case of ssh the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` variable does *not* work.

Perhaps it's a good idea to use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) for the command execution? It can handle a few things for you although it won't solve your password problem. If you are connecting through ssh than I would recommend setting up private key authentication.

See this question for more info on passwordless rsync through ssh: [How to automate rsync without asking for password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681788/how-to-automate-rsync-without-asking-for-password-prompt?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see, I am not using ssh to connect to the server. Rsync connects to me to the server and transfers the file. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: @sachitad: do you have an rsync server running on the remote server? If not, than it's highly likely that you are indeed using ssh. By default rsync uses ssh when connecting to remote systems.

Comment: I got that. What might be the solution to fix my problem?

Comment: Yes, rsync is avaiable on both local and remote machines.

Comment: @sachitad: there are 2 possible solutions. 1. use public/private key authentication so you don't need a password. 2. set up a rsyncd server so you don't need a password or can pass the password like this. I would recommend setting up a public/private key (http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)

Comment: While setting up public/private key, I can only set it up on the server where files will be transferred beacase the client will enter their password in a form. Is that possible?

Comment: After setting up rsync server, can I pass password like I did in my code?

Comment: @sachitad: with public/private key you will need to have the public key on the remote server and a passwordless private key on the connecting server. If you would be using a password for key authentication than you would have the same problem.

Comment: @sachitad: alternatively... fabric has the ssh code wrapped so you might be able to use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339735/fabric-password