# set up rsync cron job with stored password

Tags: cron, rsync, mount

I'm writing an "install" script that will create an rsync cron job on client machines to sync with our network disk. Because I'd like to automate this setup process as much as possible, I don't want to require clients to exchange pubkeys.

These two other questions seem to imply that there's no way to use rsync as a cron job with a stored password without ssh:

[How to automate rsync without asking for password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681788/how-to-automate-rsync-without-asking-for-password-prompt)
https://superuser.com/questions/325715/rsync-cron-job-with-a-password?answertab=active#tab-top

However, would it be possible (and a nonterrible idea) if, to get around this, I bookended the rsync command with a mount/unmount of the network disk, using a stored password, and then rsynced to the mount point instead?

Thanks!